# ios time stretching song from ipod library

Tags: ios, audio, avplayer

I'm looking for a way to change the tempo of the song playing. Requirement is, that it is read directly from the ipod library. I know of Dirac3LE (which owner changed and I didn't yet get a reply if they change their 32bit policy) and Superpowered (which does not directly play from the ipod-library).

I also know of AVPlayer's rate property, but I heard the stepsize is limited.

Does anyone know any option?

Thanks!

Comment: any luck finding another option to achieve what you wanted? I have the same problem and looking for a solution :/

Comment: For now I've limited myself to avaudioplayer, which does a reasonable job. I thought about using the MTAudioProcessingTap, but dismissed it as overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to go native. I would use [Audio Units](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) architecture and [kAudioUnitSubType_NewTimePitch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AUComponentServicesReference/index.html) unit.

Playing audio from iPod Library thru AudioUnits is kind of hard but this approach is worth the effort if you need low latency processing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction. I've found MTAudioProcessingTap but have to check if that works the way I want.